# Run a process on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, process

I'm new on MVC!
I want to run a process on my web app (not for bad purpose), this process can do something, for example it can write a text to a file .txt!
On my local PC, it work well but when I publish it on to host provider, it not work!
How I can do this?
This is my code:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ModuleMaple/ModuleMaple.exe");
Process myproc = new Process();
myproc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
myproc.StartInfo.Arguments ="some argument"
myproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myproc.Start();
myproc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting account or is it a VPS, dedicated, etc.?

Comment: Are you expecting it to run on the client or the server?

Comment: My first guess is that permissions are more tightly controlled on your server, likely your are using medium trust.  Wrap this code in a try/catch and make note of the exception, it will offer some clue why this fails.

Comment: I am using a free host: www.somee.com

Comment: I expect it run on server, not client, because my app run at server and return somthing to client!

Comment: @KhoiNguyen Ok, so you have shared hosting. It's likely the case then that Inter-Process Communication is disabled.

Comment: so, is there any way to do that? that exe file can do something that mvc can't, i need it for my webb app!

Comment: @KhoiNguyen You'd have to change hosting providers to a host that offers a Virtual Private Server or a Dedicated Managed Server which will allow you to configure it however you'd like.